# Github cli logout from all devices?

Tags: github, command-line-interface

I have deleted all the SSH Keys from github account and one thing confuses me is with gh auth login I've kept the login at previous workplace, so how do I logout with gh cli from all devices?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your [GitHub application settings](https://github.com/settings/applications) and under the "Authorized OAuth Apps" tab you can revoke access to the GitHub CLI application.